# jQuery :visible working but :hidden does not

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on this [website](http://www.johnpaulpet.com).

Here is the code for the menu trigger on the left sidebar:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){
  jQuery('.nav-animate nav').hide('slide', 500);
  jQuery('.nav-animate').hide();

 jQuery(".x-btn-navbar").click(function(){
  jQuery('#dimmer').fadeToggle(500);
  jQuery('.nav-animate').fadeToggle(500);
  jQuery('.nav-animate nav').toggle('slide', {direction: "left"}, 750);

// I am trying to show only the middle line when the navigation is closed 
// and change the `.menu-p` text by checking whether the navigation has
// display:none or display:block, like this:

  if(jQuery(".nav-animate").is(":visible")) {
    jQuery("span.line.top").css('background-color', '#fff');
    jQuery('span.line.bottom').css('background-color', '#fff');
    jQuery('.menu-p').html('CLOSE')
  }

// The above part works perfectly, however the part below doesn't:

  if(!jQuery(".nav-animate").is(':visible')) {
    alert('hidden');
    jQuery('span.line.top').css('background-color', '#262628');
    jQuery('span.line.bottom').css('background-color', '#262628');
    jQuery('.menu-p').html('MENU');
  }
 });
});
```

I tried using `if(jQuery(".nav-animate").is(":hidden")) {//...}`, and `if(jQuery(".nav-animate").css('display') == 'none') {//...}` but both doesn't work.

My guess, when you click to "CLOSE" it does the `:visible` or `:hidden` check, but the menu is still open at the time you click so it still doesn't have the `display:none` until the click event performs that. In that case, what can I do?

Thanks in advance for your time and suggestions.

Comment: did you try $('element:hidden') ?

Comment: Like Awena said, did u try doing `if(jQuery(".nav-animate").is(':hidden'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

animation related methods will affect the visibility check, so check the state before call to toggle

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.nav-animate nav').hide('slide', 500);
    jQuery('.nav-animate').hide();

    jQuery(".x-btn-navbar").click(function () {
        jQuery('#dimmer').fadeToggle(500);
        //negate since fadetoggle will toggle the state
        var visible = !jQuery('.nav-animate').stop().is(':visible');
        jQuery('.nav-animate').fadeToggle(500);
        jQuery('.nav-animate nav').toggle('slide', {
            direction: "left"
        }, 750);

        // I am trying to show only the middle line when the navigation is closed 
        // and change the `.menu-p` text by checking whether the navigation has
        // display:none or display:block, like this:

        if (visible) {
            jQuery("span.line.top").css('background-color', '#fff');
            jQuery('span.line.bottom').css('background-color', '#fff');
            jQuery('.menu-p').html('CLOSE')
        } else {
            // The above part works perfectly, however the part below doesn't:
            alert('hidden');
            jQuery('span.line.top').css('background-color', '#262628');
            jQuery('span.line.bottom').css('background-color', '#262628');
            jQuery('.menu-p').html('MENU');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add condition else on one your block condition right.. It's mean will be run if first condition block not true.

```
if(!jQuery('.nav-animate').stop().is(':visible')) {
    jQuery("span.line.top").css('background-color', '#fff');
    jQuery('span.line.bottom').css('background-color', '#fff');
    jQuery('.menu-p').html('CLOSE')
  }

 else{
 // to do

}
```

Comment: I tried this already, but didn't work. I've got the solution though, thanks!

Comment: my answer is same with Arun P Johny, why you say that is not work, and you say in Arun P Johny if that is work?.. SO..?

Comment: I commented that BEFORE you edited your answer and used his method to solve my problem. That's not a good start to stackoverflow. If yours was helpful too, I'd love to accept your answer. Don't forget that people can see the edits, such as: http://i.imgur.com/nKLzvgm.png